# Why is Go's escape analysis behaving differently when simple type is passed to two different functions with same signature

Tags: go, escape-analysis

I don't quite get why Go's escape analysis says that a local integer variable escapes to the heap when it is passed to `fmt.Fprintln` while it is not escaping when it is passed to another self-written function with the same signature as `fmt.Fprintln`. I hope the two scenarios A and B below should make the problem more clear.

**Scenario A: `x` escapes to heap**
Take the following content of `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    x := 73
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, x)
}
```

When you now run `go build -gcflags "-m"` you see an output that indicates that the `x` escapes to the heap. The output says something along the lines of

```
...
.\main.go:10:14: x escapes to heap
...
```

**Scenario B: `x` does not escape to heap**
Now take the following content of `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    x := 73
    myOwnPrintFunction(os.Stdout, x)
}

//go:noinline
func myOwnPrintFunction(w io.Writer, a ...interface{}) {
    println(a)
}
```

Running `go build -gcflags "-m"` again you see an output that indicates that `x` no longer escapes to the heap. The output now says something along the lines of

```
...
.\main.go:10:20: x does not escape
...
```

I don't get the difference here. I would have thought that scenario A is correct since `x` is passed to a variadic function that accepts an arbitrary number of `interface{}` arguments. But apparently that's wrong since the variable no longer escapes when it is passed to the self-written function `myOwnPrintFunction` which is also a variadic function accepting an arbitrary number of `interface{}` arguments and where the compiler is instructed to not inline this simple function.

Comment: This is an unspecified implementation detail and depends on the compiler used. The underlying reason could be that fmt.Fprintln does **much** more than println. All this has nothing to do with how the function is called or if it is your own function or from the stdlib but if the escape analysis can prove that the variable can be stack allocated.